# Golang cross compiling with CGO inside docker image

Tags: docker, go, gcc, cgo, buildx

**Requirement**: An application has to be containerised as a docker image and needs to support `arm64` and `amd64` architectures.

**Codebase**: It is a golang application that needs to make use of [git2go](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go) library and must have `CGO_ENABLED=1` to build the project. The minimum reproducible example can be found [here on github](https://github.com/Ravikc/gitoperations).

**Host machine**: I am using arm64 M1 mac and docker desktop to build the app but the results are similar on our amd64 Jenkins CI build system.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM golang:1.17.6-alpine3.15 as builder

WORKDIR /workspace
COPY go.mod go.mod
COPY go.sum go.sum

RUN apk add --no-cache libgit2 libgit2-dev git gcc g++ pkgconfig

RUN go mod download

COPY main.go main.go

ARG TARGETARCH TARGETOS

RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 GO111MODULE=on GOOS=${TARGETOS} GOARCH=${TARGETARCH} go build -tags static,system_libgit2 -a -o gitoperations main.go

FROM alpine:3.15 as runner

WORKDIR /
COPY --from=builder /workspace/gitoperations .
ENTRYPOINT ["/gitoperations"]
```

**Build steps**:

```
docker buildx create --name gitops --use
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --pull .
```

This setup works but the build is taking way too long when building for different arch. The time difference between this specific build step:
`RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 GO111MODULE=on GOOS=${TARGETOS} GOARCH=${TARGETARCH} go build -tags static,system_libgit2 -a -o gitoperations main.go` is always 10x longer when building for different arch:

example:

1. On arm64 M1 mac (without rossetta): Building arm64 executable takes ~30s and amd64 takes ~300seconds.
2. On our amd64 Jenkins CI system: Building arm64 executable takes 10x longer than building amd64 executable.

This build times can be seen by looking at the `docker buildx build` command output.
I believe (and I can most certainly be wrong) its happening because docker is using `qemu` emulation when building for a cpu architecture thats not the same as host machine's cpu arch. So I want to make use of golang cross-compilation capabilities to speed up the build times.

**What I have tried**: I thought of having a single `builder` stage in this dockerfile for arm and amd arch by trying this syntax:
`FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM golang:1.17.6-alpine3.15 as builder`.
But using the same docker build commands after making this change to dockerfile gives build errors, this is what I get when running on arm64 M1 mac:

```
 > [linux/arm64->amd64 builder 9/9] RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 GO111MODULE=on GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -tags static,system_libgit2 -a -o gitoperations main.go:
#0 1.219 # runtime/cgo
#0 1.219 gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-m64'
```

After reading through [golang CGO documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#hdr-Using_cgo_with_the_go_command) I think this error is happening because `go` is not selecting the correct `c` compiler that is able to build for both architectures and I need to set the `CC` env variable to instruct `go` which `c` compiler to use.

**Question**: Am I right in assuming that `qemu` is causing the build time difference and it can be reduced by using golang's native cross-compilation functionality?
How can I make `go build` compile for amd64 and arm64 from any host machine using docker desktop as I dont have any experience working with `C` code and `gcc` and I am not sure what value I should set for `CC` flag in the `go build` command if I need to support `linux/amd64` and `linux/arm64`?

Comment: You can try base image Golang ubuntu, I got error when try to build CGO on Alpine

Answer (score 1):

##### On the arm64 machine or container, install x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc , `debian:bookworm` is what I'm using.

```
# apt-get install g++-x86-64-linux-gnu libc6-dev-amd64-cross
# export CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
# export CXX=x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
```

##### Maybe you need to install other amd64 libs on the arm64 platform

```
# dpkg --add-architecture amd64 
# apt-get update
# apt-get install libjpeg-dev:amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to compile C code on go you need to set `CC` variable to arm cross compiler. You can see your `CC` variable by `go env`. The error you have is related with the native compiler in the host system you use. You should `apk add gcc-arm-none-eabi` in your dockerfile. After you downloaded necessary cross compilation tools. You need to link your gcc command to compiler you have downloaded via command I mentioned. Then you should be able to compile your application for arm64.

Could you also share your `go env` output. You might have to edit `GOGCCFLAGS` variable too.

Comment: You seem to have overlooked that the question explicitly says "FROM golang:1.17.6-alpine3.15", so the question is about Alpine. "sudo apt-get install" doesn't make sense in an Alpine-based image, and would also be wrong with respect to the sudo part in any Debian/Ubuntu-based image. Please fix your answer.

Comment: @TheDiveO Thanks, I missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is already a clean and neat solution in form of [@tonistiigi/xx](https://github.com/tonistiigi/xx)'s [xx . Dockerfile cross-compilation helpers](https://github.com/tonistiigi/xx/blob/master/README.md#go--cgo). While I had came across this repository while looking into Docker's multi-arch building-related Github actions I initially totally missed its importance.

The documentation has a section dedicated to [Go / Cgo](https://github.com/tonistiigi/xx/blob/master/README.md#go--cgo) that explains how to cross-compile using CGO on Alpine:

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM tonistiigi/xx AS xx

FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM golang:alpine
RUN apk add clang lld
COPY --from=xx / /
ARG TARGETPLATFORM
RUN xx-apk add musl-dev gcc
ENV CGO_ENABLED=1
RUN xx-go build -o hello ./hello.go && \
    xx-verify hello
```

`xx-apk` installs *target* platform-specific packages, whereas `apk` installs the *build* platform-specific packages, as we're using `FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM ...`.

`xx-go` conveniently wraps the `go` command, supplying the required target-specific settings under the hood. And the final `xx-verify` is a nice touch to check that the resulting binary in fact is for the *target* platform, and not accidentally for the build platform if these differ.

For my [@thediveo/lxkns](https://github.com/thediveo/lxkns) service image, the build times for linux/amd64+arm64 on a free Github action runner have dropped from 25mins down to 7mins, so approx. 3.5× as fast.